# add contact form7 shortcode in jquery

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

I'm trying to insert cf7 via shortcode in my jquery function. In my script it goes like hits:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).on("click", ".helpful #smthWrong", function (e) {
        jQuery(".helpful ").html(<?php echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='107' title='Kontaktų forma 1']"); ?>);
        });
        </script>
```

When I check in console, there is error of unexpected token < and results goes like this:

```
jQuery(".helpful ").html(<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f107-o1" lang="lt-LT" dir="ltr">
```

when I wrap my php code in ' ' , I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token and results goes like this:

```
jQuery(".helpful ").html('<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f107-o1" lang="lt-LT" dir="ltr">
```

I read that it's possible to add shortcode with ajax, but maybe there is solution add shortcode in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this using jquery as jquery will only work after the webpage is loaded into the browser, so even if you add a shortcode using jquery it will be of no use as the shortcodes are rendered on server and not in browser.

But you can achieve this using ajax.